# Explain How to change front cart icon in magento 2

Tags: magento, icons, magento2, cart

Can someone advise how to change front cart icon in magento 2. Can you full please explain process within the css thanks in advance

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182258/how-to-change-the-shpping-cart-icon-in-magento-2-and-make-to-change-color-on-mou?rq=1